# Can't get findAndModify or Update to work in MongoDB. I am getting the data I want to place in my db from my ajax call, but nothing is working

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my  ajax code:

```
$(function () {

   $("#upvoteClick").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {upvote: 2},
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"http://localhost:9000/api/upvote"
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Process success');

    })
  })
});
```

Here is my post handler in express

```
var express = require('express');
var postDB = require("./data/postDB");

var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

router.post('/upvote', function (req, res, next) {

  var data = req.body.upvote;

  postDB.connect
      .then(db => db.posts.findAndModify({
          query: {title: "Will this work"},
          update: {$inc: {upvote: data}},
          new: true})
      .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(next));

  console.log('process SHOULD be done');

});
```

Picture of the post in the db

[Picture of the post in the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3syRy.png)

here is my postDB code which connect to my db

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/crowddistdb";
var connect = MongoClient.connect(url);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection(url);

var Post = require("../admin/postModel");

module.exports = {
    connect,
    Post,
    close: function () {
        connect.then(db => db.close());
        mongoose.disconnect();

    }
};
```

I am successfully getting the number in the 'data' variable from AJAX to Express but there is something wrong with my Mongo code. I have the almost exact same way of connecting to my db and filtering through the docs in other places so i am super confused why it isnt working here.

Not sure if this helps, but my POST call registers as still 'pending' in chrome dev tools.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: can you show the post document where title equals "Will this work"? I am wondering whether you have this document in database.

Comment: What mongodb driver you using to connect and query? Im actually worried about promise chains. Maybe driver didn't support it. And you need to use callback?

Comment: @notionquest Just edited the post and put a screen shot of it in my db. Does that help?

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I am using mongoose and these promise chains work in other areas of my app using the same postDB.connect. Cant figure out why it wouldnt work here...

Comment: Maybe this would help. But i dont see findAndModify method in mongoose docs. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html . They have findOneAndRemove and others. They all use findAndModify but no direct call. Try to change from FindAndModify to findOneAndUpdate..Maybe this will solve issue.Hope this helps.

Comment: Also in native driver findAndModify deprecated. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify So maybe mongoose remove support of it.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk Thank you very much. fineOneAndUpdate did the trick and the mongoose docs helped. I was on docs.mongodb.com and it said nothing about findAndModify being deprecated. I will use the github link you've posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the current value using this

```
postDB.connect
      .then(db => db.posts.update(
          {title: "Will this work"},
          {$inc: {upvote: 1}},
          {new: true})
      .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(next));
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `findAndModify`should look something like following:

```
postDB.connect
      .then(db => db.posts.findAndModify(
          {title: "Will this work"},
          {},
          {$set:{$inc: {upvote: data}}},
          {new: true})
      .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
      .catch(next));
```